# CDH 4.2.0 and Ganglia compatibility

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, ganglia

I am using CDH 4.2.0 cluster. In order to monitor the cluster, i am planning to install Ganglia. I found a [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4675) which said Ganglia 3.1 is not compatible with hadoop 0.21.0. Can someone guide me, which version of Ganglia is compatible with CDH 4.2.0..

Answer (score 0):

CDH 4.2.0 actually comes with Hadoop 2.0. Check CDH packaging here: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/PkgVer/3.25.2013/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_topic_7.html

Hadoop 2.0 has a metrics context specifically for Ganglia 3.1. You can find the javadocs here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/metrics/ganglia

I'm in the process of setting this up now. I'll come back and share my experience if I have time (and remember).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I installed Ganglia 3.1.7 in CDH 4.3.0 and CDH 4.2.0. Both worked fine without any issues.